# Swift Playground XCPShowView "Unable to satisfy constraints"

Tags: animation, swift-playground

I'm trying to get a Live View to show a simple animation in a Swift Playground. Whenever I import the XCPlayground framework to execute the `XCPShowView` function i get this error:

`Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:_CGPointMake`

The error changes for a few other "symbols" as well, including `CGRectMake`.
After being advised to modifying my code to remove the "make" from methods such as `CGRectMake` I still get an error from Xcode when I try to animate my view. The error message is really long, but basically it says

`"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want."`

Here is the code I am trying to work with:

```
//Circle Button
class timerButtonGraphics: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let colorGreen = UIColor(red: 0.310, green: 0.725, blue: 0.624, alpha: 1.000)
        let colorRed = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 93/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 100)
        var bounds = self.bounds
        var center = CGPoint()
        center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2
        center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2
        var radius = 61
        var path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: CGFloat(0.0), endAngle: CGFloat(Float(M_PI) * 2.0), clockwise: true)
        path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 100)
        path.lineWidth = 2
        if strokeRed == true {
            colorRed.setStroke()
        }
        else {
            colorGreen.setStroke()
        }
        path.stroke()
    }
    var strokeRed = true
    }

var test = timerButtonGraphics(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 400, width: 400, height: 400))

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: nil, animations: {
    test.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.5, 0)
    }, completion: nil)

XCPShowView("Circle Animation", test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this, maybe it can help you

```
test.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Comment: I don't get an error anymore, but my Live View doesn't show an animation, it simply shows a still image of my drawn circle

Comment: I've started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235362/cabasicanimation-in-swift-playground)