# CALayer Subclass Repeating Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-animation

I'm attempting to create a CALayer subclass that performs an animation every `x` seconds. In the example below I'm attempting to change the background from one random color to another but when running this in the playground nothing seems to happen

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import QuartzCore

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200, height: 200))
XCPShowView("view", view)

class CustomLayer: CALayer {

    var colors = [
        UIColor.blueColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    ]

    override init!() {
        super.init()

        self.backgroundColor = randomColor()

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")

        animation.fromValue = backgroundColor
        animation.toValue = randomColor()
        animation.duration = 3.0
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        addAnimation(animation, forKey: "backgroundColor")

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func randomColor() -> CGColor {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
        return colors[index]
    }
}

let layer = CustomLayer()
layer.frame = view.frame
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Comment: From what I can see, you have the same "from" and "to" values for all repetitions of the animation.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't get any animation at all?

Comment: Yes. No animation happens. I get a random color and nothing after. @DavidRönnqvist I see what your saying but how would I implement the animation in such a way that it "asks" for a new color for each repeat of the animation?

Comment: If it animates between new values it's no longer the _same_ animation. Create a new animation and add that to the layer.

Comment: Related to not getting any animation in a playground: I would close your question as a duplicate of [CABasicAnimation in Swift Playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235362/cabasicanimation-in-swift-playground). But that question doesn't have an accepted answer, so I can't close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of a repeating animation are only setup once, so you can't change the color on each repeat. Instead of a repeating animation, you should implement the delegate method, 
`animationDidStop:finished:`, and call the animation again from there with a new random color. I haven't tried this in a playground, but it works ok in an app. Notice that you have to implement init!(layer layer: AnyObject!) in addition to the other init methods you had.

```
import UIKit

class CustomLayer: CALayer {

    var newColor: CGColorRef!

    var colors = [
        UIColor.blueColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    ]

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init!(layer: AnyObject!) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }

    override init!() {
        super.init()
        backgroundColor = randomColor()
        newColor = randomColor()
        self.animateLayerColors()
    }


    func animateLayerColors() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        animation.fromValue = backgroundColor
        animation.toValue = newColor
        animation.duration = 3.0
        animation.delegate = self

        addAnimation(animation, forKey: "backgroundColor")
    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
        backgroundColor = newColor
        newColor = randomColor()
        self.animateLayerColors()
    }


    private func randomColor() -> CGColor {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
        return colors[index]
    }
}
```